# Api Platform property types are always STRING

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

Despite my efforts with type hinting and `@var int` annotations, Api Platform’s interpretation of this property is always `string`.

#### Consider this property:

```
/**
 * @var int $geonameId The ID of a Geonames.org city/place/town
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="bigint", options={"unsigned": true}, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Type(type="int", message="Geoname id must be an integer")
 */
protected $geonameId;

public function getGeonameId(): ?int
{
    return $this->geonameId;
}

public function setGeonameId(int $geonameId = null): self
{
    $this->geonameId = $geonameId;
    return $this;
}
```

**I get the following schema out from Api Platform:**

```
geonameId  string
           nullable:  true
           The ID of a Geonames.org city/place/town
```

And when I try submit `"geonameId": 123456` I get the following error:

> *The type of the "geonameId" attribute for class <Entity> must be one of "string" ("int" given).*

I know about the `@ApiProperty` annotation to customise attributes etc. but I don't want to have to verbosely define the type just to accept an integer when I have already used type hinting and/or @var annotation.

Does anybody see anything wrong with what I am doing / expecting? Thanks in advance...

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/basic-mapping.html - Looks like Doctrine maps a BIGINT as a string. 

`bigint: Type that maps a database BIGINT to a PHP string.`

Not sure if you could try with integer instead? Something to think about..

Comment: Thanks @Bossman, that worked, please answer instead of a comment and I will mark as correct. Can't believe that distinction, and it does make sense why, I just never thought that would be the culprit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Doctrine maps a BIGINT as a string.

Ref:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/basic-mapping.html

> bigint: Type that maps a database BIGINT to a PHP string.